# Getting a MalformedQueryString exception when creating an SQS standard queue

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-ruby

I am trying to create an AWS SQS standard queue locally with [`localstack`](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) and using ruby's `aws-sdk-sqs` library. I am running into an error when passing in parameters into the `RedrivePolicy` attribute. I believe I am using the API documentation correctly as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/SQS/Client.html#create_queue-instance_method).

I did some research and it seems that the parameters passed into the `RedrivePolicy` attribute should be JSON-formatted but I could be wrong.

This is my code:

```rb
c = Aws::SQS::Client.new
c.create_queue(queue_name: "my_queue", attributes: {"RedrivePolicy" => "{\"maxReceiveCount\":\"5\"}"})
```

And this is what I'm getting:

```
Aws::SQS::Errors::MalformedQueryString (MalformedQueryString; see the SQS docs.)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To specify a RedrivePolicy you also have to give it a deadLetterTargetArn where it will put the failed messages.

So you'd need to create that queue first, then pass it's Arn along to the second call:

```
c.create_queue(queue_name: "my_queue", 
   attributes: {"RedrivePolicy" => "{\"maxReceiveCount\":\"5\",
                                     \"deadLetterTargetArn\": \" #{deadLetterArn}\"}"})
```